# how to install virtualenv and flask on your cmd to use in Python?

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a forum application using Python.
I've realized that in order to do that I must install Virtualenv and a framework such as flask.
First I tried to install Virtualenv with the help of internet tutorial using the command "pip install virtualenv" and I got this Error:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/84/3a/9d656ec2535fa5f6680d55ef93a05f890bd1b2ad6f2bf97b34a679abf365/virtualenv-20.0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

then I searched in the web for a solution and tried using the command :
pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user virtualenv

It seemed to do the trick at the time but then I tried to move along with creating an Environment using the commands: ls, cd, vi, etc and the cmd didn't recognize them...

Do you have any idea what seems to be the problem and how can I fix it? I am pretty new to Python..

Thanks in advance! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzMKw.jpg)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use virtualenv and not venv (which is built into Python and does not require installation)?

Comment: I want to be able to visualize my database table that contains the forum text content so that every user can see it in the user interface. can I do it using venv? if so, could you please explain how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no particular reason for using virtualenv, you can use **venv** to create a virtual environment to run your application in. **venv** is built into all newer versions of Python, and therefore does not require installation.

Follow the following steps to set up a venv virtual environment for the project to run in:

Open a Bash session:

on Linux: open a terminal

on Windows: open Git Bash (much more convenient than cmd in this context)

Navigate to the directory in which you want your virtual environment to be stored in.
Create a new virtual environment called "myvenv":

on Windows:

```
python -m venv myvenv
```

on Linux:

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
```

Activate the virtual environment:

on Windows:

```
myvenv/Scripts/activate
```

on Linux:

```
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

(you will see *(myvenv)* in front of your command prompt, if it is activated)

If you documented all your requirements in a *requirements.txt* file like e.g.

```
Flask==1.1.1
requests==2.22.0
```

you can install all dependencies with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Otherwise you have to install every package separately with

pip install [PACKAGE]

To run your python application within this virtual environment, activate the environment first and then run

```
python [YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE].py
```

**As requested in the comments by OP, here a little bit more background on this:**

Python is an interpreted language. If your application has dependencies (e.g. Flask), those dependencies must be accessible to the interpreter. Otherwise your application will not run. You can install the packages for your dependencies e.g. with pip.

Since different applications have different dependencies and sometimes even different specific versions of a package, it is not wise to install packages system-wide. Instead, one uses virtual environments to create a dedicated isolated environment for every project to run in.

> This means that each project can have its own dependencies, regardless
>   of what dependencies every other project has.

(see [this](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#why-the-need-for-virtual-environments) Real Python article)

To make it easier to get the virtual environment with all the necessary dependencies for your project running on different systems, it is common practice to document all your project’s dependencies in a *requirements.txt* file. This way everyone trying to run your project, knows exactly which dependencies your project has. Additionally, you do not have to install every package separately within a newly created virtual environment but can use a one-line command for pip to install all dependencies listed within the *requirements.txt* file.

Comment: what is a bash session? and how do i connect between requirements.txt file to my appliction.py file? thank you!

Comment: bash is the command line processor on Linux. On Windows, cmd.exe is the command line processor. Yes, you can run bash on Windows, but let's not get confused.

Comment: @DafyAbraham I edited my answer to hopefully make things more clear. And I included a little bit more background at the end so you can get a better overall picture.